# missing config file and blocking scripts after sshguard installation

Tags: raspbian, ssh

I am trying to install `sshguard` on Raspbian 9. The installation went fine. However, I can't find any default sshguard config, which should be in the `/etc/sshguard/sshguard.conf` file, and also the blocking scripts, which should be in the `/usr/libexec/sshguard/` folder.
I use sshguard on an Ubuntu system, where everything that should be there is.
I need to install sshguard on multiple raspberry pi devices using a script. I can handle the configuration, but I have no idea where to find the blocking scripts.

[image: list of sshguard blocking scripts on Ubuntu 22.04 system]

Comment: Why are you running Stretch? It's two releases behind current (Buster then Bullseye) and three releases behind the next version (Bookworm). You're more likely to get help if you use a current release (Bullseye or Bookworm) and not some ancient old crap.

Comment: @Dougie I'd like to have the latest version. Unfortunately, the RPi I am writing this script for is corporate and there are dozens of them at customers. Updating would be difficult and it is not in my purview to make that decision.

Comment: The newer versions still boot on my 2013 512MB Raspberry Pi model B. So stop using the old crap.